# Ionic password dissappearing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, passwords

I was trying to do something like this

[image]

using this code

```
 <div class="row" id="passwordRow">
        <div class=".col-80">
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="8"  ng-required="true" ng-hide="showPassword" >
            <input type="text" id="passwordRaw" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" ng-show="showPassword">
        </div>
       <div class="col">
         <i class="icon ion-eye" id="passwordView" on-touch="showPassword = !showPassword"></i>
       </div>
</div>
```

But what happens is, if i type something and press it the first time it shows nothing. If i type and press it a second time, it shows the correct value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in password input you assign password to user object in the controller scope while in the second field you retain password from rootScope. since there is nothing there so it shows empty input. when you assign a password to `text input` a password property is created in the parent scope. the thing is that those two properties can be different. ex. you can set for the first time "abc" to to `password input` and when you click button and got `text input` type abcdef. if you change back again to `password input` you'll see your `password input` is 3 letters long and not 5 and it has the original value you typed earlier ("abc")

Answer (score -1):

you can remove **user from user.password** like this :

```
<div class=".col-80">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"  ng-model="password" ng-minlength="8"  ng-required="true" ng-hide="showPassword">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password"  ng-model="password" ng-show="showPassword">
</div>
```

> cz ng-model should be same for both the input value